# How to delete a Product

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

How to delete the following query using asp.net core web api.

Query :

```
Select * 
From catalog.Industy.Category.Subcategory.Product 
Where Product.Id="97c27069-4a16-44c3-bdf1-627c8ea339fa"
```

json body:

```
{
    "id": "9fc41e97-c32e-45e6-853f-ae7993cbc773",
    "Industy": {
        "Id": "40f5a6f5-2947-469c-8d29-6aa84de982cb",
        "Category": {
            "Subcategory": {     
                "Product": {
                    "Addons": {   
                    },
                    "MethodOfPreparation": {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should first read the documentation of using CosmosDB:
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started)

On this page you can see how you can query your product and then delete this record from your collection:

```
 var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<YourDocumentModel>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
 "<your sql>",
 queryOptions);
```

with this result you can update the object (`yourDocumentModelObject`) and remove the product from the subcategory. 
Afterwards save it back to the collection in doing something like:

```
await client.UpsertDocumentAsync<YourDocumentModel>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
yourDocumentModelObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

With cosmosdb sql api, it should be

```
 SELECT *
    FROM Products p
    WHERE p.Industy.Category.Subcategory.Product.Id = "97c27069-4a16-44c3-bdf1-627c8ea339fa"
```

where Products is the name of the container

Comment: my json body look like above.

Comment: i wrote a query document . how to delete it.please any idea please